# C# System.InvalidOperationException DisplayClass0_0 error while getting token

Tags: c#, linq, authentication, token

I need to get token when I register, but it gives me an error

Hello everyone.

I got that error when I was trying to register to my project on Postman:

https://anotepad.com/note/read/tgrka47d

(System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown while attempting to evaluate the LINQ query parameter expression 'value(DataAccess.Concrete.EntityFramework.EfUserDal+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).user.Id'. See the inner exception for more information.)

My UserManager is here:

`

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Business.Abstract;
using Core.Entities.Concrete;
using DataAccess.Abstract;

namespace Business.Concrete
{
    public class UserManager : IUserService
    {
        IUserDal _userDal;

        public UserManager(IUserDal userDal)
        {
            _userDal = userDal;
        }

        public List<OperationClaim> GetClaims(User user)
        {
            return _userDal.GetClaims(user);
        }

        public void Add(User user)
        {
            _userDal.Add(user);
        }

        public User GetByMail(string email)
        {
            return _userDal.Get(u => u.Email == email);
        }

    }
}
```

`

My AuthManager is here:

`

```
using Business.Abstract;
using Business.Constants;
using Core.Entities.Concrete;
using Core.Utilities.Results;
using Core.Utilities.Security.Hashing;
using Core.Utilities.Security.JWT;
using Entities.DTOs;

namespace Business.Concrete
{
    public class AuthManager : IAuthService
    {
        private IUserService _userService;
        private ITokenHelper _tokenHelper;

        public AuthManager(IUserService userService, ITokenHelper tokenHelper)
        {
            _userService = userService;
            _tokenHelper = tokenHelper;
        }

        public IDataResult<User> Register(UserForRegisterDto userForRegisterDto, string password)
        {
            byte[] passwordHash, passwordSalt;
            HashingHelper.CreatePasswordHash(password, out passwordHash, out passwordSalt);
            var user = new User
            {
                Email = userForRegisterDto.Email,
                FirstName = userForRegisterDto.FirstName,
                LastName = userForRegisterDto.LastName,
                PasswordHash = passwordHash,
                PasswordSalt = passwordSalt,
                Status = true
            };
            _userService.Add(user);
            return new SuccessDataResult<User>(user, Messages.UserRegistered);
        }

        public IDataResult<User> Login(UserForLoginDto userForLoginDto)
        {
            var userToCheck = _userService.GetByMail(userForLoginDto.Email);
            if (userToCheck == null)
            {
                return new ErrorDataResult<User>(Messages.UserNotFound);
            }

            if (!HashingHelper.VerifyPasswordHash(userForLoginDto.Password, userToCheck.PasswordHash, userToCheck.PasswordSalt))
            {
                return new ErrorDataResult<User>(Messages.PasswordError);
            }

            return new SuccessDataResult<User>(userToCheck, Messages.SuccessfulLogin);
        }

        public IResult UserExists(string email)
        {
            if (_userService.GetByMail(email) != null)
            {
                return new ErrorResult(Messages.UserAlreadyExists);
            }

            return new SuccessResult();
        }

        public IDataResult<AccessToken> CreateAccessToken(User user)
        {
            var claims = _userService.GetClaims(user);
            var accessToken = _tokenHelper.CreateToken(user, claims);
            return new SuccessDataResult<AccessToken>(accessToken, Messages.AccessTokenCreated);
        }
    }
}
```

`

My AuthController is here:

`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Business.Abstract;
using Entities.DTOs;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AuthController : Controller
    {
        private IAuthService _authService;

        public AuthController(IAuthService authService)
        {
            _authService = authService;
        }

        [HttpPost("login")]
        public ActionResult Login(UserForLoginDto userForLoginDto)
        {
            var userToLogin = _authService.Login(userForLoginDto);
            if (!userToLogin.Success)
            {
                return BadRequest(userToLogin.Message);
            }

            var result = _authService.CreateAccessToken(userToLogin.Data);
            if (result.Success)
            {
                return Ok(result.Data);
            }

            return BadRequest(result.Message);
        }

        [HttpPost("register")]
        public ActionResult Register(UserForRegisterDto userForRegisterDto)
        {
            var userExists = _authService.UserExists(userForRegisterDto.Email);
            if (!userExists.Success)
            {
                return BadRequest(userExists.Message);
            }

            var registerResult = _authService.Register(userForRegisterDto,userForRegisterDto.Password);
            var result = _authService.CreateAccessToken(registerResult.Data);
            if (result.Success)
            {
                return Ok(result.Data);
            }

            return BadRequest(result.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

`

My EfUserDal is here:

`

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Core.DataAccess.EntityFramework;
using Core.Entities.Concrete;
using DataAccess.Abstract;
using System.Linq;

namespace DataAccess.Concrete.EntityFramework
{
    public class EfUserDal : EfEntityRepositoryBase<User,CarRentalContext>,IUserDal
    {
        public List<OperationClaim> GetClaims(User user)
        {
            using (CarRentalContext context = new CarRentalContext())
            {
                var result = from operationClaim in context.OperationClaims
                    join userOperationClaim in context.UserOperationClaims
                        on operationClaim.Id equals userOperationClaim.OperationClaimId
                    where userOperationClaim.UserId == user.Id
                    select new OperationClaim {Id = operationClaim.Id, Name = operationClaim.Name};
                return result.ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

I need to get a token when I register. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You picked up the wrong lines from your stacktrace to focus on.

It states the following in the inner exception:

```
 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at DataAccess.Concrete.EntityFramework.EfUserDal.GetClaims(User user) in /home/mert/Desktop/Project/ReCapProject/DataAccess/Concrete/EntityFramework/EfUserDal.cs:line 20
```

Which means you have a variable on line 20 in your `EfUserDal` which does not have a value at runtime.

Since the next line mentions `ToList`, I'm guessing `result` is `null` after evaluating the query. Use debugging to see what value each variable in your query is getting before it's evaluated. Probably one of them is `null`

Comment: In my AuthController, (var result = _authService.CreateAccessToken(registerResult.Data);)'s ".Data" is null in Debugging mode. Because in my DataResult class, "Data=data" code is missing. Thank you for helping.